# How can we decide whether use to writeTypedList/ readTypedList or writeList/ readList

Tags: android

Currently, I still wondering when we implement `Parcelable` interface for a class, how can we decide when to use `writeTypedList/ readTypedList` or `writeList/ readList`

### Read

```
// Using writeTypedList
parcel.writeTypedList(watchlistColumnTypes);

// Using writeList
parcel.writeList(watchlistColumnTypes);
```

### Write

```
// Using readTypedList
watchlistColumnTypes = new ArrayList<>();
in.readTypedList(watchlistColumnTypes, WatchlistArrayRecyclerViewAdapter.ColumnType.CREATOR);


// Using readList
watchlistColumnTypes = new ArrayList<>();
in.readList(watchlistColumnTypes, WatchlistArrayRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getClassLoader());
```

Both workable for me. But, I'm not sure what is the difference between both, and how can we choose among them?

Comment: if you have `Parcelable` item use `writeTypedList` / `readTypedList` - it is more efficient than `writeList` / `readList`

Comment: Do you find more reference on the efficiency? I can see the documentation `Unlike the generic writeList() method, however, only the raw data of the objects is written and not their type`, which implicitly (not so clear) regarding the efficiency.

Comment: sure: [Parcel.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/1a008c1/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java), see how `writeList` is implemented

Comment: @pskink Fair enough. Then I think the rule is to use `writeTypedList / readTypedList` whenever we could. Do you think you want to post the above as answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the rule of thumb is that, we should use `writeTypedList` or `readTypedList` whenever we could, and use `writeList` or `readList` whenever you need to.

This is because `writeTypedList` or `readTypedList` seems to have better performance.

According to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/1a008c1/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#117

> There are also some methods that provide a more efficient way to work
>   with Parcelables: writeTypedObject(T, int), writeTypedArray(T[], int),
>   writeTypedList(List), readTypedObject(Parcelable.Creator),
>   createTypedArray(Parcelable.Creator) and
>   createTypedArrayList(Parcelable.Creator). These methods do not write
>   the class information of the original object: instead, the caller of
>   the read function must know what type to expect and pass in the
>   appropriate Parcelable.Creator instead to properly construct the new
>   object and read its data.